# Serverless - Options for communicating between services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I have a few different services (generated by the Serverless Framework) that need to communicate between each other. The data is sensitive and requires authentication.

My current strategy is to create an api key for each service communicate between services using json web token like the token below.

```
fM61kaav8l3y_aLC/3ZZF7nlQGyYJsZVpLLiux5d84UnAoHOqLPu4dw3W7MiGwPiyN
```

What are some other options for communicating between services? Are there any downsides to this approach? To reiterate, the request needs to be authenticated and appropriately handle sensitive data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need sync or async communication?
A good approach would be to use events, because aws-lambda is designed as an event based system. So you could use [SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/details/) or [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/details/) to decouple your services.

If you just want to make calls from one service to another you could invoke the lambda function directly via the aws-sdk [see docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property). So you would not add an API Gateways endpoint and your lambdas would stay private.

To better anwser your question you should give a short overview of your application and and an example of an interservice call you would make.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. The communication is async. A simple example would be one service that does a task and another that sends an email (but I only want an authorized server to be able to trigger the function that sends the email).

Comment: @samcorcos sounds like you want to turn that dependency around. You don't want the email to fail to send because the email service is down. You want it to be delayed in that case. So one solution could be to put SendEmail commands on SQS and let a lambda listen to those. That way if the lambda is offline the emails to send just pile up and are sent when the lambda is online again.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you intend to make the various functions in a given a service private.  In doing so, each service will likely have serverless.yml file that resembles the following: 
[Image shows the setup for api keys used with a serverless framework rest api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nvAj.png)

While this is a suitable approach, it is less desirable than using ** Custom Authorizers**.

Custom Authorizers allow you to run an AWS Lambda Function before your targeted AWS Lambda Function. This is useful for Microservice Architectures or when you simply want to do some Authorization before running your business logic.

If you are familiar with the onEnter function when using ReactRouter, the logic among Custom Authorizers is similar.

Regarding implementation, since different services are leveraged to deploy various functions, consider deploying the function to AWS and noteing the ARN of the Lambda function.  Follow these links to see the appropriate setup for the custom authorizer.

[These images show the serverless.yml file for using custom authorizers when the authorizers are not part of the service but rather deployed on lambda already](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PA2f.png)

The following github project  aws-node-auth0-custom-authorizers-api/frontend is a good example of how to implement Custom Authorizers when the authorizer funciton is in the same service as the private function.  Note your situation differs slightly yet you should expect their authorizer function logic to be simliar - only the project structure should differ